# The line integral of F along a helix

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

> "Let $T$ be the smallest positive real number such that the tangent to the helix $(\cos t)i + (\sin t)j + (t/(2^{1/2}))k$ at $t=T$ is orthogonal to the tangent at $t=0$ . Then $F = (x)j - (y)i$ along the section of the helix from $t = 0$ to $t = T$ is $2$ .

How ? Here $i$,$j$,$k$ are the three unit vectors along $x$,$y$,$z$-axes , respectively" . Please help with this problem...I have simply evaluated the line integral to be $T$...but the answer is $2$...I think the orthogonality has some role in it...but I don't understand how...I have just begun vector calculus !

Comment: You could show us, what you did and we can say, where your mistake is.

Comment: I substituted x=cos t,y= sint and evaluated the integral of F.dr i.e (-ydx + xdy ), i.e (((sin t)^2)+((cost)^2)))dt, i.e simply dt from t=0 to t=T to get the value of the integral F.dr along the section of the helix as T...however I have not taken account of the orthogonal tangents as stated in the question

Comment: Here is a hint, if you look at the helix from along the z-axis it will look like a circle, the z component makes no difference here. The beginning of this circle is on the x axis at $x=1$, what is the earliest time you will get a line orthogonal to this first tangent line?

Comment: Alternatively, the velocity (tangent) vector for this curve is $\vec{r}'(t)=-\sin{t}\hat{i}+\cos{t}\hat{j} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{k}$, you then enforce orthogonality via $\vec{r}'(0) \cdot \vec{r}'(T) = 0$. This will yield a very simple equation for the value of $T$

Comment: Sorry sir but I didn't get you...are you asking me to consider polar of that circle then...also how do we find the tangent...if we could have got del(phi) i.e the directional derivative along the direction of the normal and by the qs it would also be orthogonal.

Comment: My second comment is an alternative and will give the correct value of T, have you tried solving it?

Comment: Yes sir as you have shown the relation how to derive an equation for T and thank you sir I have reached the answer